# ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable using Keras functional API

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am implementing the following Keras Model for an image captioning network using keras functinoal API (tf.keras):

```
import glob
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import pickle
from tqdm import tqdm
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers, Input
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import sequence
from tensorflow.keras.applications import InceptionV3
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras import Model
import nltk
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

def data_generator(batch_size = 32):
    partial_caps = []
    next_words = []
    images = []

    df = pd.read_csv(folder_drive + 'flickr8k_training_dataset.txt', delimiter='\t')
    df = df.sample(frac=1) #shuffle rows
    iter = df.iterrows()
    c = []
    imgs = []
    for i in range(df.shape[0]):
        x = next(iter)
        c.append(x[1][1])
        imgs.append(x[1][0])


    count = 0
    while True:
        for j, text in enumerate(c):
            current_image = encoding_train[imgs[j]]
            for i in range(len(text.split())-1):
                count+=1

                partial = [word2idx[txt] for txt in text.split()[:i+1]]
                partial_caps.append(partial)

                # Initializing with zeros to create a one-hot encoding matrix
                # This is what we have to predict
                # Hence initializing it with vocab_size length
                n = np.zeros(vocab_size)
                # Setting the next word to 1 in the one-hot encoded matrix
                n[word2idx[text.split()[i+1]]] = 1
                next_words.append(n)

                images.append(current_image)

                if count>=batch_size:
                    next_words = np.asarray(next_words)
                    images = np.asarray(images)
                    partial_caps = sequence.pad_sequences(partial_caps, maxlen=max_len, padding='post')
                    yield [[images, partial_caps], next_words]
                    partial_caps = []
                    next_words = []
                    images = []
                    count = 0

image_input = Input(shape = (2048,))
x = layers.Dense(embedding_size, activation='relu')(image_input)
image_output = layers.RepeatVector(max_len)(x)
image_model = Model(inputs=image_input,outputs = image_output)
image_model.summary()

caption_input = Input(shape = (max_len,))
y = layers.Embedding(vocab_size,embedding_size,input_length=max_len)(caption_input)
y = layers.LSTM(256,return_sequences=True)(y)
caption_output = layers.TimeDistributed(layers.Dense(embedding_size))(y)
caption_model = Model(inputs = caption_input, outputs = caption_output)
caption_model.summary()

conca = layers.Concatenate(axis=1)([image_model.output,caption_model.output])
z = layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(256, input_shape = (max_len,300), return_sequences=False))(conca)
z = layers.Dense(vocab_size)(z)
final_output = layers.Activation('softmax')(z)
final_model = Model(inputs = [image_model.input,caption_model.input], outputs = final_output)
final_model.summary()
```

[Plot of the model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8ggW.png)

```
final_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer="rmsprop", metrics=['accuracy'])
final_model.fit_generator(data_generator(batch_size=2048), steps_per_epoch = samples_per_epoch//2048, 
                          verbose=1,epochs = 50)
```

When running the fit_generator method, I always get the following error:

```
Epoch 1/50
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-225-9cb298634256> in <module>()
      1 final_model.fit_generator(data_generator(batch_size=2048), steps_per_epoch = samples_per_epoch//2048, 
----> 2                           verbose=1,epochs = 50)

12 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    966           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    967             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 968               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    969             else:
    970               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:571 train_function  *
        outputs = self.distribute_strategy.run(
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:951 run  **
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2290 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2649 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:541 train_step  **
        self.trainable_variables)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1804 _minimize
        trainable_variables))
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py:521 _aggregate_gradients
        filtered_grads_and_vars = _filter_grads(grads_and_vars)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py:1219 _filter_grads
        ([v.name for _, v in grads_and_vars],))

    ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['embedding_6/embeddings:0', 'dense_14/kernel:0', 'dense_14/bias:0', 'lstm_10/lstm_cell_18/kernel:0', 'lstm_10/lstm_cell_18/recurrent_kernel:0', 'lstm_10/lstm_cell_18/bias:0', 'time_distributed_6/kernel:0', 'time_distributed_6/bias:0', 'bidirectional_4/forward_lstm_11/lstm_cell_20/kernel:0', 'bidirectional_4/forward_lstm_11/lstm_cell_20/recurrent_kernel:0', 'bidirectional_4/forward_lstm_11/lstm_cell_20/bias:0', 'bidirectional_4/backward_lstm_11/lstm_cell_21/kernel:0', 'bidirectional_4/backward_lstm_11/lstm_cell_21/recurrent_kernel:0', 'bidirectional_4/backward_lstm_11/lstm_cell_21/bias:0', 'dense_17/kernel:0', 'dense_17/bias:0'
```

Can anyone help me to identify where is the error because i have never seen it before and i have been checking similar posts in SO but any of the solutions there has worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
final_model = Model(inputs = [image_input ,caption_input ], outputs = final_output)
```